# SPSS split a string variable into two or three separate new variables depending on the content

Tags: string, split, spss

Im trying to split a variable into two or three separate parts but for the life of me I cannot get it to work.

I want to split a string `ADATE10` into two parts `ADATE`/`10`, or a string `F8.2` into `F`/`8`/`2`.
So for example the starting variables are like this:

```
+-------------+
| PrintFormat |
+-------------+
| A10         |
| F4          |
| ADATE10     |
| F8.2        |
| F4.1        |
| A100        |
+-------------+
```

And I want to get to this:

```
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+
| PrintFormat | typeA | typeW | typeD |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+
| A10         | A     | 10    |       |
| F4          | F     | 4     |       |
| ADATE10     | ADATE | 10    |       |
| F8.2        | F     | 8     | 2     |
| F4.1        | F     | 4     | 1     |
| A100        | A     | 100   |       |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

My main experience with programming is C# and some VBA macros, so here's the approach that I tried in SPSS. Basically I want to loop backwards through the characters in the string value, when the character is a `.` then thusfar it was the decimal, when the character is not a NUMBER then thusfar it was the width part, and the rest to the beginning is the datatype indicator:

```
* add the new variables

string typeA(a50).
string typeW(a50).
string typeD(a50).

* split from the existing variable

string #char(a1).
string #part(a50).
compute #part = "".
compute #partindex = 1.

loop #pos = char.substr(PrintFormat,#pos,1) to 1.
    compute #char = char.substr(PrintFormat,#pos,1).

    do if (#char = ".").
        compute typeD = #part.
        compute #part = "".
    else if (MISSING(NUMBER(#char, f4)) AND #partindex = 1).
        compute typeW = #part.
        compute #part = "".
        compute #partindex = 0.
    end if.

    compute #part = concat(#part, #char).
    * COMPUTE #pos = #pos - 1. * ??
END loop.
compute typeA = #part.
execute.
```

That gave so many errors that I don't even know where to begin, and I can't seem to debug it properly, so instead I tried a simpler approach just using `INDEX` and `REPLACE`, like so:

```
if (INDEX(PrintFormat, "A") = 1) COMPUTE typeA = "A".
if (INDEX(PrintFormat, "F") = 1) COMPUTE typeA = "F".
if (INDEX(PrintFormat, 'ADATE') = 1) COMPUTE typeA = "ADATE".

COMPUTE typeW = replace(PrintFormat, typeA, "").

COMPUTE #posdec = char.index(typeW, ".").
if (#posdec > 0) COMPUTE typeD = char.substr(typeW, #posdec, 2).

execute.
```

but this also gives an error right on the first line

> An equals sign was not found when excepected afer a target variable in
> a COMPUTE command.

So after working on it for quite a while I have to give it a rest for now. I can only say that SPSS syntax works much differently then I expected it to. What am I doing wrong here, and how can I split a string value like this into separate bits in SPSS?

Comment: Note - in your second block of code, after `if` you shouldn't add `compute`. For example in  `if (#posdec > 0) COMPUTE typeD = char.substr(typeW, #posdec, 2).`  you should get rid of `compute`. In the same block  you used `index` a few times - this should be `char.index`.

Comment: For your first block of code - try to fix your loop definition - it is completely flawed - then see if the rest works any better.